# How to read base64 String from Random Access File (Android)

Tags: java, android, randomaccessfile

i have a random access file that contains a base64 string

```
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
```

The problem is that when i read it using this code, i can't seem to return the exact thing that is in the text file.

```
File f = new File("fprint.txt");
RandomAccessFile randomFile = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
String fromFile = randomFile.readLine();
```

When i log "fromFile", i get

```
AwFmIY4A+f6ABoACgAKAAoACgAKAAoACgAKAAoACgAKAAoACgAKAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1
```

Which is way shorter than what i put in. I want to able to read everything in the file the exact same way. Thank you

Edited: log code

```
Log.i("Check File", "Content of File: " + fromFile );
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code you used to log the Base64 encoded file?

Comment: just added it @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: try using readFully instead of readLine

Comment: ready fully expects a byte array and not a string @Blackbelt

Comment: indeed. And what would be the problem ?

Comment: works fine for me with and without final \n in file. a you sure your logger do not strip long lines? or maybe some unprintable symbol in file that break line

Comment: no it doesn't @rustot, think i've got what i need now. Works like a charm. Thanks for all the suggestion guys.. You've been helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `read()` method, instead of `readLine()`, for example:

```
public static String getBase64FromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r");
    String result = "";
    int b = file.read();
    while (b != -1) {
        result = result + (char) b;
        b = file.read();
    }
    file.close();

    return result;
}
```